# How to load resources in Nuxt js only when required

Tags: javascript, webpack, nuxt.js

[image]

In Chrome console it shows a warn message that the **resource is being preloaded** but since in nuxt.js all the resource by default is set to preload

How do I only load the resources only when it is required?

Comment: What did you looked so far? Also, can you post the error as text rather than image please?

Comment: @kissu i just used lazy import and it worked fine for fingerprintjs. So now this module will only load on demand and will not preload during DOM load.
But for commons/app this is the js bundle that is created by nuxt js framework and how can these bundles not be preloaded if it is not required and how can we only load such bundles only when required?

Comment: In case somebody is still trying to fix this, got an open issue here https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/10613

Answer (score 1):

You can disable `prefetch` and `preload` with [this configuration](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-render#resourcehints)

```js
export default {
  render: {
    resourceHints: false
  }
}
```

---

You can also do [it per link](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-router#prefetchlinks)

```html
<nuxt-link to="/about" :prefetch="false">About page not prefetched</nuxt-link>
```

Here is also a valid configuration

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
export default {
  router: {
    prefetchLinks: false
  }
}
```

`prefetch` and `preload` are not exactly the same thing, but I didn't looked deeply into it as of right now.

Comment: Thank you for the information will try to use this and set all those unwanted pages to prefetch false

Comment: Whoever tries this on NUXT Bridge, it seems not to work in your case.
For reference https://github.com/nuxt/bridge/issues/346

Comment: @Sonny49 looking at how Nuxt3 is close to be fully stable, I guess that the core team will (and even, is) not really focus on maintaining Nuxt bridge anymore for obvious reasons (too much work for just not enough benefit).

Comment: @kissu when you reckon they will release NUXT3? I am honestly sick of NUXT Bridge, full of bugs.

Comment: @Sonny49 Nuxt3 is already available under RC13. Expect it to be 100% stable around RC15.